# Draw text in a Canvas and multiple lines

Tags: java, android, paint, android-canvas

I'm starter with Canvas and Paint. I want to paint a text in a Canvas but it can be longer than the original Bitmap. So the text go out the Bitmap.

Is there some kind of automatic manager for this making a new line when the end is reached? or should I play with heights and distances? Thanks

Comment: If you don't mind using Swing, [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) will manage your mutli-line text displays for you. Canvas is an AWT heavyweight object, which can be kind of tricky to mix with lightweight controls. JTextArea is a lightweight, which is likely to cause you fewer problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you can manage this with a [StaticLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) or [DynamicLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/DynamicLayout.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to draw text with StaticLayout:

```
// init StaticLayout for text
StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(
  gText, paint, textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

// get height of multiline text
int textHeight = textLayout.getHeight();

// get position of text's top left corner
float x = (bitmap.getWidth() - textWidth)/2;
float y = (bitmap.getHeight() - textHeight)/2;

// draw text to the Canvas center
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(x, y);
textLayout.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

See [my blogpost](http://www.skoumal.net/en/android-drawing-multiline-text-on-bitmap/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you also look at this code snippet found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15092729/1759409

As it will manage the writing of your text within a certain width and height and automatically draws onto the canvas correctly.